# How to show the same control in a view without repeating it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

Here i have a scenario like i have 4 textbox in a page..if there is value available in database i have to show those 4 values in those 4 corresponding textbox else i have to show those 4 textbox as empty.Now i have achieved it by checking the model count as below

```
if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
   // binding the model values to those 4 textbox
}
else
{
  //show 4 textbox 
}
```

But here i am repeating those 4 same controls inside both if and else condition.Is there anyother way to achieve this.Any suggestion??

Comment: from your code looks like you are using List of model...can you show us more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have Test Model as below

```
public class Test
{
    public string TextBox1 { get; set; }
    public string TextBox2 { get; set; }
    public string TextBox3 { get; set; }
    public string TextBox4 { get; set; }
}
```

Now at controller check that value is exist in DB or not as per return value

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        var valExit == DBCheckFunction();
        if(valExit ! = null)
        {
            test.TextBox1 = valExit.val1 ;
            test.TextBox2 = valExit.val2 ;
            test.TextBox3 = valExit.val3 ;
            test.TextBox4 = valExit.val4 ;
            return View(test);
        }
        else
        {
            return view(test);
        }

    }
```

Your view be as simple and bind model with it and need to write only once

```
@model NameSpace.Models.Test

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.TextBox1)
.
.
.
so on
```

It will do than automatically

I hope this is what you want

Comment: this is correct..but i think he is using `List<Model>` that's why he is checking `Model.Count()`

Comment: @Nilesh if it is than I will try alternate solutions . Thanks for your concern .

Answer (score 0):

Try tablelayoutpanel, you can limit its size and only one control can be added in a single cell, this will avoid your repeation problem

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your model to textboxes which will automatically put data in textbox if it present in your model.
For e.g.
This is my Model TextBoxValuesModel.cs

```
public class TextBoxValuesModel
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
    public string value3 { get; set; }
    public string value4 { get; set; }
}
```

Now in controller I am putting some values in model & then sending it to my view TextBoxValues.cshtml

```
  public ActionResult TextBoxValues()
    {
        Models.TextBoxValuesModel tc = new Models.TextBoxValuesModel();
        tc.value1 = "me";
        tc.value2 = "you";
        tc.value3 = "are";
        tc.value4 = "go";
        return View(tc);
    }
```

Now in my view I will bind this model with textboxes like this

```
@model DisplayModes.Models.TextBoxValuesModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "TextBoxValues";
 }

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.value1)
<br/>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.value2)
<br/>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.value3)
<br/>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.value4)
```

Here if I dont put any data in object of model in controller then textboxes will be empty & if I put values then It will be shown in textbox.